# C#: How to use CategoryAttribute.Appearance Property

Tags: c#, user-controls, attributes, windows-forms-designer

I have read a bit about [Design-Time Attributes for Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx). There I found an attribute called [CategoryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx). On that page it says that

> The CategoryAttribute class defines the following common categories:

And then lists up a number of common categories. One of them are for example [Appearance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.appearance.aspx). I thought, brilliant! Then I can use `[Category.Appearance]` instead of `[Category("Appearance")]`! But apparently I couldn't? Tried to write it, but Intellisense wouldn't pick it up and it wouldn't compile. Am I missing something here? Was it maybe not this those properties were for? If not, what are they for? If they are, how do I use them?

And yes, I do have the correct `using` to have access to the `CategoryAttribute`, cause `[Category("Whatever")]` do work. I'm just wondering how I use those defined common categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on MSDN it's only a getter property, not a setter.

```
public static CategoryAttribute Appearance { get; }
```

In fact, here's what the code looks like using Reflector:

```
 public static CategoryAttribute Appearance
    {
        get
        {
            if (appearance == null)
            {
                appearance = new CategoryAttribute("Appearance");
            }
            return appearance;
        }
    }
```

So it doesn't do a heck of a lot.

The only use I can see for it, is something like this:

```
            foreach (CategoryAttribute attrib in prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false))
            {
                bool result = attrib.Equals(CategoryAttribute.Appearance);
            }
```

Basically, when using reflection to look at the class, you can easily check which category this belongs to without having to do a String comparison. But you can't use it in the manner you're trying to unfortunately.

Comment: hm, that's just plain annoying... hehe. what's the point in a constant defined attribute when it is only usable in one end. Oh well. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: May be you could create your own Categories Class. Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2009/05/07/categoryattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The static property is accessed via CategoryAttribute.Appearance. But the attribute system does not allow you to invoke code in an attribute declaration and I guess that is why it wont compile for you. You will probably have to settle for [Category("Appearance")].

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C# 6 there is finally a better alternative: `[Category(nameof(CategoryAttribute.Appearance))]`.